# What is the angle $<(BDE,ADH)$?

Tags: geometry

What are ways to determine the angle $<(BDE,ADH)$ (the angle between the two planes passing through the points B,D,E and the points A,D,H respectively)?

[image: A rectangular prism with height 4, length 4 and width 5]

Comment: Assuming this prism is rectangular, we know that $m\angle ADH = 90^{\circ}$

Comment: @NasuSama That is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by $\angle(BDE,ADH)$? $\angle BDE$ and $\angle ADH$ are two different angles. Are you referring to the angle between the two planes passing through the points $B,D,E$ and the points $A,D,H$ respectively?

Comment: @RahulNarain Yes

Comment: That is quite non-standard notation as far as I'm aware; you would do well to spell it out in the future. I see that now that you've explained it, Berci has pointed you towards the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/635760/18398

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. The angle between two planes is the same as the angle between their normal lines.
2. You can find a normal vector to plane $PQR$ by e.g. the cross product $\vec{PQ}\times\vec{PR}$.
3. Calculate angle of vectors $a,b$ by scalar product: $\cos \angle(a,b)\ =\ \displaystyle\frac{a\cdot b}{|a|\,|b|}$.

Comment: Can you do it without using vectors?

Comment: No. But for example, $\vec{BD}=(-5,4,0)$ as it goes $-5$ to the right, $+4$ ahead and $0$ upwards, and $\vec{BE}=(-5,0,4)$. Haven't you studied cross product and scalar product?