# How to determine the angle $\angle(DCN, ABP)$?

Tags: geometry

How to determine the angle $\angle(DCN, ABP)$  (the angle between the two planes passing through the points $D,C,N$ and the points $A,B,P$ respectively) without using vectors? See rectangular prism:

[image]

Comment: See my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636383/what-is-the-angle-bde-adh

Comment: What's up with $Q,M$?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

In this post I use $U$ and $V$ to denote $N$ and $P$. The angle you are seeking equals the angle made by $BV$ and $CU$.

Imagine yourself looking from $BCGF$'s side. Then you see
[image]

You should be able proceed and find $\angle UXV$ from here.

Comment: ∠UXV isn't the smallest angle. Doesn't it suppose to be the smallest angle?

Answer (score 0):

An elementary level question like this one needs an explanation through the basics.

I added a few lines to your diagram as[image]

Step 1 – Find the line of intersection of the red and blue planes.

-- It is ST, a line through X and parallel to AB.

Step 2 – Find lines, on the red plane, such that they are perpendicular to ST. (There are many.)

-- In this case, PX is a good choice.

Step 3 – Repeat Step 2 for the blue plane.

-- In this case, CX is a good choice.

Step 4 – Select those chosen ones such that they meet at the same point.

--  In this case, PX and XC are the good choices and that intersecting point is X.

Step 5 – Angle PXC is then the angle of intersection of these two planes.

We are lucky to have angle PXC lying on the plane FBCG.